# Center TextViews vertically in RelativeLayout when one or more has visibility set to GONE

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am trying to create a list item layout with 4 items. It is very similar to the example [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html) with some key differences:

- the RelativeLayout layout_height may be larger than listPreferredItemHeight
- the image is a CheckBox
- there are three TextViews
- The top and middle TextViews could have visibility set to GONE

What I would like is: If _label is gone, then _message and _definition should be evenly weighted in the layout. If _label and _message are gone, _definition should be centered. I have tried several variations of height, width, gravity, layout_gravity and I even tried to solve this with a LinearLayout (both as the whole layout and just to contain the vertical text). The only way I can get this to work is if I set layout_height to listPreferredItemHeight, but then only two of the text views fit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/alarm_list_item_able" 
        android:text=""     
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="True"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="True"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="True"
        android:layout_centerVertical="True"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/alarm_list_item_label" 
        android:text="Label place holder" 
        android:singleLine="True"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/alarm_list_item_able"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="True"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/alarm_list_item_message" 
        android:text="Message place holder"
        android:singleLine="True"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_below="@id/alarm_list_item_label"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/alarm_list_item_able"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />          
    <TextView android:id="@+id/alarm_list_item_location" 
        android:singleLine="True"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
        android:layout_below="@id/alarm_list_item_message"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/alarm_list_item_able"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="(0.000, 0.000) 0m"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter getView Code using the xml from blessenm's answer

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Log.d(Global.TAG,"Position "+position);
    View newView;
    if (convertView != null ) 
        newView = convertView; 
    else { 
        LayoutInflater layout = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this); 
        newView = layout.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, null); 
    }
    String tmp1 = "Place Holder Label"
    TextView label = (TextView)newView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_list_item_label);
    LayoutParams l = label.getLayoutParams();
    if (tmp1.matches("^\\s*$")){
        label.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(l.width,l.height,0f));
    } else {
        label.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(l.width,l.height,1f));
    }
    label.setText(tmp1)

    String tmp2 = "Place Holder Message"
    TextView message = (TextView)newView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_list_item_message);
    l = message.getLayoutParams();
    if (tmp2.matches("^\\s*$")){
        message.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(l.width,l.height,0f));
    } else {
        message.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(l.width,l.height,1f));
    }
    message.setText(tmp2);

    TextView location = (TextView)newView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_list_item_location);
    location.setText("location");

    return newView;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layout_gravity will only work inside a linear layout. When you want all your textviews to take even height, put them in a linearlayout with vertical orientation and give weight as 1 for all the textviews. So now all of them will take equal heights.

When you need to hide the textviews, just set their layout_weight to 0, now the remaining textview will take the full available space. And if you give the textview gravity="center", the text will be centered both vertically and horizontally.

**Edit: The xml and getView method**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/alarm_list_item_able" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:onClick="onClick" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/alarm_list_item_able" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/alarm_list_item_label" 
            android:text="Label place holder" 
            android:singleLine="True" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/alarm_list_item_message" 
            android:text="Message place holder"
            android:singleLine="True" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/alarm_list_item_able"
            android:layout_below="@id/alarm_list_item_label"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/alarm_list_item_location" 
            android:singleLine="True"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="(0.000, 0.000) 0m" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/alarm_list_item_able"
            android:layout_below="@id/alarm_list_item_message"/> 
    </LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

The getview method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.label = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(
                R.id.alarm_list_item_label);
        holder.msg   = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(
                R.id.alarm_list_item_message);
        holder.loc   = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(
                R.id.alarm_list_item_location);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(holder != null){
        if(data.get(position).mLabel.equals("")){
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams labelLp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,0);
            if(!data.get(position).mMsg.equals("")) {                   
                holder.label.setLayoutParams(labelLp);                  
                holder.msg.setText(data.get(position).mMsg);                    
                holder.loc.setText(data.get(position).mLoc);
            } else {
                holder.label.setLayoutParams(labelLp);                  
                holder.msg.setLayoutParams(labelLp);                    
                holder.loc.setText(data.get(position).mLoc);
            }
        } else {
            holder.label.setText(data.get(position).mLabel);
            holder.msg.setText(data.get(position).mMsg);
            holder.loc.setText(data.get(position).mLoc);
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this approach already and it suffers from the same problem I described above.

Comment: Im not sure what your problem is as I am able to do it will a linear layout as I mentioned by changing the layout_weight values. Show me your getview method in adapter? Let me see what you are doing. Btw the xml i used is in my answer

Comment: I have edited my question to include my getView code (it is modified slightly to reduce the lines of code). The getView code uses the layout you have provided. With your layout and my getView, the result is a listItem that is too small and hides some of the TextViews.

Comment: The answer is super close to what worked for me; I refactored the if(holder != null) block. The key was: if mLabel (or mMsg) is an empty string, set layout height to 0, otherwise call setText.